# How execute Python with Applescript in Apple system?

Tags: python, anaconda, applescript

i have the problem of executing python from applescript.

i created this test with this folders and files and system:

1. Anaconda last version **Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-x86_64**
2. Desktop folder named **pymac**, in /Users/andrea/Desktop and file test.py

```
with open("/Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/output2.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Hello")
```

3. in folder /Users/andrea/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel script file **test.scpt**:

```
on test()
    do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/pymac; /Users/andrea/AnacondaNew/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py"
end test
```

other script **test2.scpt**:

```
on test()
    do shell script "/usr/bin/python3 /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py"
end test
```

from Terminal:

If I run the following command, it works

```
/usr/bin/python3 /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py
```

However, the same command run from within 'test2.scpt', does not work from script editor and from the terminal with osascript

command

```
/Users/andrea/AnacondaNew/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py
```

works, same errors if i use scpt file or osascript

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Add debugging to your script to help find more information

```
try:
    with open("/Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/output2.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello")
except Exception as e:
    with open("/Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/errorlog.log", "w") as f:
        f.write("Err: " + str(e))
```

and also make sure your environment variables are set including PythonPath CondaPath and your Scriptpath

```
set condaPath to "/path/to/conda"
set pythonPath to "/path/to/python"
set scriptPath to "/Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py"
```

Comment: hi, i can't execute python file from applescripts, no problem if i send command from Terminal, i have done the suggested variations. Problem is in applescript. I need applescript to use python from my excel .xlsm vba files. Vba excel mac cant create objects as excel from windows.

Comment: try creating a bash script that you can call from applescript instead that activates the conda environment and then executes the python script afterwards.

Comment: yes, now script works perfect with Applescript, activate_conda.sh is the key. THX for your precious help

Comment: post your bash script

Comment: now i must resolve the next step: run applescript from vba

Comment: Solved look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670317/how-execute-python-directly-from-excel-vba-mac/77677521#77677521

Answer (score 0):

its the bash script that works well for me, i save this file in original desktop folder:

command from terminal:

```
osascript "/Users/andrea/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/run_script.scpt"
```

my code script:

```
do shell script "/Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/activate_conda.sh"
do shell script "/usr/bin/python3 /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py"
```

my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the name of the active Conda environment
conda_env=$(conda info --envs | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}')

# Print the name of the active Conda environment
echo "Active Conda environment: $conda_env"

# Change to the directory where your conda environment is located
cd /path/to/your/conda/env

# Activate the conda environment
source activate $conda_env

# Add any other commands you want to execute in the conda environment
# For example:
# python your_script.py

# Deactivate the conda environment when done
conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

To run AppleScript from VBA on a MacOSX, you can use the MacScript function

```
Sub RunBashScript()
    Dim script As String

    scriptPath = "/PATH/TO/BASHSCRIPT.sh"

    Dim applescriptCmd As String
    applescriptCmd = "do shell script " & Chr(34) & "source " & scriptPath & Chr(34)

    MacScript applescriptCmd
End Sub
```