# How execute Python directly from Excel Vba Mac?

Tags: python, excel, vba, applescript

First i solved the problem to execute Python with AppleScript with Conda environment: [How execute Python with Applescript in Apple system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77669971)

Now i must run applescript from my vba code but i have error or no-action.

File are and script are same of previous link, vba code:

**First test**

```
Sub RunScript0()
    Dim myScriptResult As String
    myScriptResult = AppleScriptTask("/Users/andrea/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/MyAppleScriptFile.scpt", "MyAppleScriptHandler", "/usr/bin/python3 /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py")
End Sub
```

**Second test**

```
Sub RunScript1()
    Dim scriptPath As String
    Dim command As String

    ' Set the path to your AppleScript file
    scriptPath = "/Users/andrea/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/run_script.scpt"

    ' Build the full command
    command = "osascript """ & scriptPath & """"

    ' Run the command using the Shell function
    Call Shell(command, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Errors in code, no action.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 365 for Apple computers
osX Sonoma 14.2

I solved simply with:

1. put an alias of applescript file (located in /Users/andrea/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel) in working excel folder file (located in /Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac)
2. my applescript file:

`on myapplescripthandler(paramString)`

`do shell script "/usr/bin/python3 " & paramString`

`end myapplescripthandler`

3. my vba code to call applescript:

   Sub RunScript()

   ```
   Dim res As String
   Dim myScriptResult As String

   myScriptResult = AppleScriptTask("PythonTest.scpt", _ 
        "myapplescripthandler", _ 
        "/Users/andrea/Desktop/pymac/test.py")

   MsgBox myScriptResult
   End Sub
   ```

That's all, i hope to help